# Dynamically inserted Select drop down field is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a select drop down field where the options are inserted using JavaScript. It works fine when the page loads for the first time, but after refreshing the select field disappears. I am using bootstrap-selectpicker.js with material-design for CSS.

> Interestingly if i clear the cache and reload the page it works again, or if i close the page and open the link again.

the callback function *fun.get_dosageUnits* fetches the options from db and loops through to create the select html, finally inserts them to div tag.

```
fun.get_dosageUnits( units => {
    let selected,selectOpt='<select class="selectpicker" name="dosageUnit" data-size="7" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Dosage Unit">';
    units.forEach((unit,index) =>{
        if(index == 0){ selected = 'selected'}
        selectOpt += `<option value="${unit.dosage_units}"${ selected}>${unit.dosage_units}</option>`;       
        selected ='';       
    });
     document.querySelector('.setDosageUnit').innerHTML = `${selectOpt}</select>`; 
});

<div class="form-group setDosageUnit"></div>
```

i think i have to re-init **bootstrap-selectpicker.js** or something can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself

```
$("#setDosageUnit").selectpicker('refresh');
```

for [reference](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)

although i welcome any suggestions on how to convert the above code to something like this...

```
document.querySelector('#setDosageUnit').selectpicker('refresh');
```

i am getting undefined function